# How force Camel Elasticsearch to not start local node in test?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel

I have a Camel-Elasticsearch endpoint configured by URI like this:

```
.to("elasticsearch://clusterName?operation=INDEX&indexName=" + elasticIndex + "&indexType=" + elasticIndexType)
```

In test, i intercept this endpoint, and merely want to confirm I've sent the payload here, by doing this:

```
elasticEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:elastic", MockEndpoint.class);
interceptRoute = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    interceptSendToEndpoint("elasticsearch:*")
            .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
            .to(elasticEndpoint);
    }
};
```

However this always prompts Camel to start a local embedded ElasticSearch, that in turn creates a data-folder I do not want on my Jenkins-server.

How do you disable the automatic creation of the local Elasticsearch-node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camel-elasticsearch component checks if [configuration.getIp() == null](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchEndpoint.java) to determine if it creates an Elasticsearch-node.

Therefore you have to specify an IP and port in the URI to disable this, as such:

```
.to("elasticsearch://clusterName?ip="+ elasticHostIp + "&port=" + elasticHostPort + "&operation=INDEX&indexName=" + elasticIndex + "&indexType=" + elasticIndexType)
```